# Load a serice worker using new URL in webpack 5

Tags: webpack

According to the webpack 5 release notes, webpack will detect entry points for web workers and service workers and create new chunks - see https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#native-worker-support

This seems to work great with web workers - the following creates a webworker called `my-worker.js`

```
function createWorker() {
  return new Worker(
    new URL(`./MyWorker.js`, import.meta.url) /* webpackChunkName: "my-worker.js" */
  );
}
```

But - when I try the same with the service worker this doesn't work :(

```
function register(options) {
  return window.navigator.serviceWorker.register(
    new URL('./ServiceWorkerController.js', import.meta.url),
    options
    /* webpackChunkName: "service-worker.js" */
  );
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working

webpack will recognise this - and make a chunk

```
function register(options) {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.register(
    new URL('./ServiceWorkerController.js', import.meta.url),
    options
    /* webpackChunkName: "service-worker.js" */
  );
}
```

when i use `window.navigator` it won't